# SQL UNION syntax

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out what the correct syntax for `UNION` is. My schema looks like is the following:

```
Players (playerNum, playerName, team, position, birthYear)
Teams = (teamID, teamName, home, leagueName)
Games = (gameID, homeTeamNum, guestTeamNum, date)
```

I need to print all `teamIDs` where the team played against the X team but not against the Y team.

So my first idea was to check for the hometeamNum and then do a check for the guesteamNum, but I am not sure home to do the proper syntax.

```
SELECT DISTINCT hometeamNum 
FROM games 
WHERE 
    guestteamNum IN 
      (SELECT teamid FROM teams WHERE teamname = 'X') AND 
    guestteamNum NOT IN 
      (SELECT teamid FROM teams WHERE teamname = 'Y') 
UNION DISTINCT
```

Comment: Why do you think this needs a union?  Your query looks pretty much what you need except for the `UNION DISTINCT` at the end (which isn't a thing - unions are distinct unless you use `UNION ALL`)

Comment: @LoztInSpace 'UNION DISTINCT` can exist e.g. see MySQL docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html - but I agree there is no absolute need to use any union here

Comment: @Used_By_Already - Ah, ok - a MySQL-ism.  Most dialects don't have this syntax as `UNION` is implicitly distinct.  Probably needs a MySQL tag then.

Comment: @LoztInSpace - yes most dialects do not include `union distinct`, and yes tagging this question with MySQL might be appropriate (that's a hint dorito777 - include the dbms vendor as a tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the home teams, this should suffice:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hometeamnum
FROM games
WHERE guestteamnum NOT IN (SELECT teamid FROM teams WHERE teamname = 'Y')
```

If you need both home teams and guest teams:

Select all teams that are not 'y' that didn't play agains 'y' as home team and didn't play against 'y' as guest team, and played against 'x' as guest team or played against 'x' as home team.

```
SELECT DISTINCT teamid
FROM teams
WHERE teamname != 'y' AND teamid NOT IN
 (SELECT hometeamnum
 FROM games INNER JOIN teams ON games.guestteamnum = teams.teamid 
 WHERE teamname = 'y'
 UNION
 SELECT guestteamnum
 FROM games INNER JOIN teams ON games.hometeamnum = teams.teamid 
 WHERE teamname = 'y')
AND teamid IN
 (SELECT guestteamnum
 FROM games INNER JOIN teams on games.hometeamnum = teams.teamid
 WHERE teamname = 'x'
 UNION
 SELECT hometeamnum
 FROM games INNER JOIN teams on games.guestteamnum = teams.teamid
 WHERE teamname = 'x');
```

Hopefully this is what you were after. There may be a more concise query out there but it's too late in the night for me to think of one :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany'
UNION ALL
SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany'
ORDER BY City;
```

Comment: This doesn't help with figuring out the syntax I need when dealing with multiple tables and different columns. From your example you are accessing 2 different tables that have the same columns.

Comment: Your comment said you were trying to figure out how to use the proper syntax of UNION, not that you wanted it written out for you, or that you don't understand joins.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NOT EXISTS` allows you to locate rows that don't exist. That is , you want teams that have played against 'X' which are rows that do exist and these can be located by using a simple join and where clause**. Then from those rows you need to find any that do not exist against the team 'Y'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        hometeamnum
FROM games
        INNER JOIN teams AS guests ON games.guestTeamNum = guests.teamID
WHERE guests.teamname = 'X'
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM games AS games2
                INNER JOIN teams AS guests2 ON games2.guestTeamNum = guests2.teamID
        WHERE games.hometeamnum = games2.hometeamnum
        AND guests2.teamname = 'Y'
        )
```

Notes.

`EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` does not actually need to return any data so it is possible to use `select 1` or `select null` or `select *`. I have used `select 1` here simply because it may be easier to understand - however I would personally prefer `select null' which stresses that no data is being returned by the exists subquery.

`EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` are both reasonably efficient and can perform better than `IN (...)`

**  for performance, and where it does not alter the result, use a join in preference to `IN ( subquery )`